# Is this Insertion Sort implementation worst case O(n)?

Tags: c++, sorting, time-complexity, insertion-sort

I know that Insertion Sort is supposed to be worst case O(n^2), but I'm wondering why the following implementation isn't O(n).

```
void main()
{
//insertion sort runs from i = 1 to i = n, thus is worst case O(n)
for (

    int i = 1,
    placeholder = 0,
    A[] = { 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 },
    j = i;

    i <= 10;

    j-- > 0 && A[j - 1] > A[j]
    ? placeholder = A[j], A[j] = A[j - 1], A[j - 1] = placeholder
    : j = ++i
)

{
for (
    int x = 0;
    x < 10; x++
) 
    cout << A[x] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}


system("pause");
}
```

There is only one for loop involved here and it runs from 1 to n. It seems to me that this would be the definition of O(n). What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: You have two for loops hidden in the definition of the first for. i goes from 1 to array.size, j potentially goes from i to 0 for each i.

Comment: The trained eye might say "don't write code like that".

Comment: @NeilButterworth i decided to take away my comment, it looked overly snarky :)

Comment: I would ask that those voting on this question vote based on the quality of the question, not the quality of the code. The question is about how to analyze complexity, not how to write code. So while the code is of undesirable quality, I think the question is reasonable from a beginner who does not yet understand what complexity measures.

Answer (score 1):

Sloppy terminology has led many people to false conclusions. This appears to be an example.

> There is only one for loop involved here and it runs from 1 to n.

Yes, there is only one loop, but what is this "it" to which you refer? I really do mean for you to think about it. Should "it" refer to the loop? That would match a fairly common, yet sloppy, use of terminology, but a loop does not evaluate to a value. So a loop cannot actually run from one value to another. The sloppiness can be overlooked in simpler contexts, but not in yours.

Normally, the "it" would really refer to the [loop control variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_variable_(programming)). With a simple loop, like `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)`, there is a one-to-one correspondence between iterations of the loop and values assigned to the control variable (which is `i` in my example). So there is an equivalence present, allowing one to refer to the loop when one really means the control variable. Saying that a loop runs from x to y really means that the *control variable* runs from x to y, and that **there is one iteration of the loop per value assigned to the control variable**. This correspondence fails in your code.

In your loop, the thing that runs from 1 to n is `i`. However, `i` is not incremented with each iteration of the loop, so "it runs from 1 to n" is *not* an accurate assessment of your *loop*. When `i` is 1, there are up to 2 iterations. That's not a one-to-one correspondence between iterations and values of `i`.  As `i` increases, the divergence from one-to-one grows. Each value of `i` potentially corresponds to `i+1` iterations, as `j` counts down from `i` to `0`. The total number of iterations in the worst case scenario for n entries is the sum of the potential number of iterations for each value of `i`: 2 + 3 + ⋯ + (n+1) = (n² + 3n)/2. That's O(n²).

*Moral of the story: writing compact, cryptic code does not magically change the complexity of the algorithm being implemented. Cryptic code can make the complexity harder to pin down, but the main thing you've accomplished is making your code harder to read.*

Answer (score 0):

Thats a very odd way to write code.But You have 2 for loops in the definition. It is not always necessary to have nested loops to have O(n^2), you can have it with recursion also. 
In simple terms O(n^2)n simply means number of operations performed when the input size is n.

Comment: The second `for` loop is for printing the result. It does not contribute to the complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score -2):

The code given is not a correct c++ code and not even close to a pseudocode.
The correct code should be like this:

```
void main()
{
 int i,j,key;
 int A[]={10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
 //cout<<"Array before sorting:"<<endl;
 //for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 //cout<<A[i]<<"\t";
 //cout<<endl;
 for(i=1;i<10;i++)
 {
  key=A[i];
  for(j=i-1;j>=0 && A[j]>key;j--)
  {
   A[j+1]=A[j];
  }
  A[j+1]=key;
 }
 //cout<<"Array after sorting:"<<endl;
 //for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 //cout<<A[i]<<"\t";
 //cout<<endl;
}
```

See, insertion sort has two loops. Outer loop is to maintain the key variable and the inner loop is to compare the elements prior to key variable with the key variable. And therefore the worst case time complexity is O(n^2) and not O(n), as the basic algorithm of insertion sort contains two loops, both of which eventually iterate n times in case of worst case i.e. when the array is inverted.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by incorrect c++ code. It compiles and sorts the array. I don't care about other ways of writing the sort, I'm curious about the one I wrote.

Comment: The code is very oddly written but seems like legal c++. Notice that most lines don't end with a semi colon and most of the code belongs to a `for` statement. Edit : Never mind, noticed that `main` has `void` return type.